# Bash array variable from loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to store a variable (**$random**) from the loop statement - currently only the last statement from the loop is printed. Please note that I would like to use this variables outside of the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for backup in $(s3cmd ls s3://bucket/ | awk '{ print $2 }')
do
latest=$(s3cmd ls $backup | awk '{ print $2 }'  | sed -n '$p')
random=$(s3cmd ls $latest | shuf | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '1p')
        s3cmd get $random $data_dir >/dev/null 2>&1
done

echo "$random
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but I think you are saying you want to keep a record of each value `$random` receives during execution of the loop.

```
declare -a randoms

for backup in $(s3cmd ls s3://bucket/ | awk '{ print $2 }')
do
latest=$(s3cmd ls $backup | awk '{ print $2 }'  | sed -n '$p')
random=$(s3cmd ls $latest | shuf | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '1p')
        s3cmd get $random $data_dir >/dev/null 2>&1
randoms+=( $random )
done

echo ${randoms[@]}
```